# Exposing the aws-rum variables in the snippet is a potential security risk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-cloudwatch

This is an open question, for some reason my submission as a general question does not go through here https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-rum-web/issues

To enable aws-rum we must expose these variables as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-rum-web/blob/HEAD/docs/npm_installation.md):

```
const config: AwsRumConfig = {
    allowCookies: true,
    endpoint: "https://dataplane.rum.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    guestRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/RUM-Monitor-us-west-2-000000000000-00xx-Unauth",
    identityPoolId: "us-west-2:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    sessionSampleRate: 1,
    telemetries: ['errors', 'performance']
  };
```

Even using env vars to hide them they eventually get exposed in the Front End, they can be found in the browser inspector. My question: Is it dangerous to have these variables exposed? Can harm be done? My company already encountered an attempt to create new IAM user and the attacker used these variables but apparently failed. I cannot see any documentation mentioning the importance of hiding these variables in env vars or the fact that its ok to have them exposed. Any evidence mentioning this would be useful to show to my company that:

- a) its ok to have them exposed or
- b) we have to hide this variables.